# reading flat files in c++

Tags: c++, data-structures

I need an opinion and also how can this be done in C++.
I have a flat file which had a mapping like below

```
Number Some text
1         Apple
2         Orange
3         Grape
```

Have can I implement logic in C++ so that in my code when I enconter the value say 1 I can getch the value thats mapped against it i.e Apple in this case.Do I have standard datastructures that can be used for this.Can you point me to some code examples for the same.

Comment: [`std::map<int,std::string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)

Comment: Or `std::unordered_map<int, std::string>`, or (if the numbers are always contiguous) just `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: Does your question concern *reading* data or *storing* them?

Comment: I'm sure I've seen this question months ago. Have you managed to parse your file or is that an issue as well? Otherwise @WhozCraig answered your question.

Comment: No I have not manageed to parse the file yet.

Comment: Is the input file *exactly* as presented? Or is the first line just there for our benefit, and the actual input file is just the content that follows? Also, are the strings after the numeric ids potentially multi-word?

Comment: The input file is some what different.But the format is same it is similar like below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I have standard datastructures that can be used for this?

In the standard library you can use `std::map` in combination of `int` for the IDs and `std::string` for the text.

Your `std::map` can initialized and used as follows:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

std::map<int, std::string> m;
m[1] = "Apple";
m[2] = "Orange";
m[3] = "Grape";
```

It's good to point out that if your indices are always contiguous and you make them start by `0` you could just use `std::vector` which maybe suits better your purposes?

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::vector<std::string> v;
v.push_back("Apple");
v.push_back("Orange");
v.push_back("Grape");

v[0]; // Apple
v[1]; // Orange
v[2]; // Grape
```